# How can i parse enum to combobox except some element?

Tags: forms, winforms, enums, combobox

I try to parse `enum` to `combobox` but i want to parse some element. For example i have prebuilt enum like `enum{apple,banana,orange}`. I want to parse only apple to combobox, how can i do without changing enum?

Comment: What's the exact issue here?  Have you tried something like this? `this.comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>() .Where(x => x >= DayOfWeek.Tuesday).ToList();`, or any criteria that you like?

Comment: I have shared enum  and i use this enum on different location of program. Some element causes crashing program if it is selected. It must not shown.  I am newbie for winforms, can you help me?

Comment: Ahmet, I believe the first comment answers your question. Please try it and if it didn't solve your problem, comeback with more details, expected result and a [MCVE] to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it solved my problem, i am glad to your answer. Thank you so much:)